# How to Convert Users from Site 'A' to Site 'B' in wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to export all the users from site 'A' and import it to Site 'B' in wordpess multisite network.

There are 35000 users in my website, I tried several plugins to export them but it is not working out for me to export.

Answer (score 0):

if you are comfirtable with using mysql then just export the wp_user table and import it to your another site